# How do we poll data from lighthouse to InfluxDB or Graphite to visualize it in Grafana

Tags: influxdb, lighthouse

I am setting up a Grafana dashboard to visualize the lighthouse / Google Page Speed Insight data. How do I poll the results from lighthouse / GPSI to InfluxDB / Graphite so that I can see the data in Grafana dashboard?

Comment: How about the Google Page Speed Insight API?

Comment: Google Page Speed Insight will run the test only for public sites and not for internal websites.

Answer (score 1):

Lighthouse doesn't natively export to Graphite however there are some npm packages that I've come across and used with varying degrees of success.

https://github.com/aykut-rocks/lighthouse-to-graphite
This utility was easy to set up, edit the configuration file with information about your Graphite server, optionally add a prefix to the metric. It generated the following graphite format metrics during a test run on metricfire.com:

- metricfire-com.**bootup-time**
- metricfire-com.**critical-request-chains**
- metricfire-com.**dom-size**
- metricfire-com.**mainthread-work-breakdown**
- metricfire-com.**redirects**
- metricfire-com.**time-to-first-byte**
- metricfire-com.**total-byte-weight**
- metricfire-com.**unminified-css**
- metricfire-com.**unminified-javascript**
- metricfire-com.**unused-css-rules**
- metricfire-com.**uses-long-cache-ttl**
- metricfire-com.**uses-optimized-images**
- metricfire-com.**uses-request-compression**
- metricfire-com.**uses-responsive-images**
- metricfire-com.**uses-webp-images**

Another option is https://www.npmjs.com/package/lighthouse-graphite

[Here's](https://grafana.com/grafana/dashboards/10288) a useful Grafana dashboard that you can import which should support the metrics generated by Lighthouse.

Alternatively, instead of using Chrome's audit tool, you could use something like [Sitespeed.io](https://www.sitespeed.io/)

I hope this helps!